# Changes in Xcode 9 not reflecting in mainStoryboard, however, same changes are reflecting in simulator

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard, ios-simulator

I am trying to set the dimensions of an image by writing code, but when I try to run the code it works and shows the changes in the simulator but *not*  in `MainStoryboard`. Why might this be happening?

```
Import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 500, width: 258, height: 64)); // set as you want
    let image = UIImage(named: "signInLogo.png");
    imageView.image = image;
    self.view.addSubview(imageView);


 }

 override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }
}
```

[image]

Comment: The code executes at runtime that's why it's not showing on the storyboard.
Also, you are not using your storyboard imageview.

Answer (score 0):

Storyboard is **NOT** a live view of what is running in your application. Storyboard is only going to display the views that are within it. If you are creating views (your `UIImageView`) pro grammatically within your `ViewController`, they won't show up in your Storyboard because they never touch it.